# mysql select in case of existing or not

Tags: mysql, select, join

i am trying to write SELECT statement which would return some elements + date difference between current time and date_created or date_edited. If field was edited i should grab date_edited from other table which updates after editing element, if it was not i should grab date_created from current one because that element do not have relationship with other edited elements table, and calculate DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_created/date_edited). I have written select which brings me edited elements with correct date, and other select which brings all elements just if they were edited it brings me incorrect date difference. So all in all i need to form single table which brings me elements with calculated date difference.

```
SELECT
table1.name,
table1.sales_stage,
users.user_name,
DATEDIFF(NOW(), table1_edit.date_edited) as DaysOnStage
FROM table1
join users on table1.assigned_user_id = users.id
join table1_edit on table1.id = table1_edit.parent_id
WHERE table1.sales_stage = table1_edit.after_value_string;
```

This one brings all edited values with correct date calculated.

```
SELECT
table1.name,
table1.sales_stage,
users.user_name,
DATEDIFF(NOW(), table1.date_created) as DaysOnStage
FROM table1
join users on table1.assigned_user_id = users.id;
```

This one brings me all elements but if they were edited ofcourse with bad date difference. Need somehow to combine these selects and form single table.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can left join the edit table and put a `ISNULL()` (`IFNULL()` in mysql) function on the date field:

```
SELECT
table1.name,
table1.sales_stage,
users.user_name,
DATEDIFF(NOW(), IFNULL(table1_edit.date_edited,table1.date_created) as DaysOnStage
FROM table1
join users on table1.assigned_user_id = users.id
left join table1_edit on table1.id = table1_edit.parent_id
WHERE table1.sales_stage = table1_edit.after_value_string;
```

Left/Outer joining tables is a must-learn for working in SQL:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

or you can use UNION with your queries:

```
SELECT
table1.name,
table1.sales_stage,
users.user_name,
DATEDIFF(NOW(), table1_edit.date_edited) as DaysOnStage
FROM table1
join users on table1.assigned_user_id = users.id
join table1_edit on table1.id = table1_edit.parent_id
WHERE table1.sales_stage = table1_edit.after_value_string;
This one brings all edited values with correct date calculated.
UNION
SELECT
table1.name,
table1.sales_stage,
users.user_name,
DATEDIFF(NOW(), table1.date_created) as DaysOnStage
FROM table1
join users on table1.assigned_user_id = users.id;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with a `left join` and then use `COALESCE()` to choose the right value:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.sales_stage, u.user_name,
       DATEDIFF(NOW(), COALESCE(te.date_edited, t1.date_created)) as DaysOnStage
FROM table1 t1 join
     users u
     on t1.assigned_user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     table1_edit te
     on t1.id = te.parent_id
WHERE t1.sales_stage = te.after_value_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

[if](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) should be helpful

```
SELECT
table1.name,
table1.sales_stage,
users.user_name,
if (table1_edit.parent_id is null, DATEDIFF(NOW(), table1_edit.date_edited), DATEDIFF(NOW(), table1.date_created)) as DaysOnStage
FROM table1
join users on table1.assigned_user_id = users.id
left join table1_edit on table1.id = table1_edit.parent_id
enter code here
```